# jQuery change background color not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a notification system and after the comment has been scrolled to i want to highlight in someway the comment specified.

I was just going to time out a background colour change but cant get it working...

Heres a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zem2kp0d/2/):

I have commented out the scrollIntoView() as it plays havoc with the jsfiddle itself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var commentid = "comment";
  //document.getElementById(commentid).scrollIntoView();
  $(commendid).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

That's the code, any silly reason why the background colour is not changing?

Comment: What's `commendid`? Shouldn't it be `commentid`? And shouldn't `var commentid = "comment";` be `var commentid = "#comment";`. Voting to close as off-topic due to typos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several issues.

1. You need to use a `#` to denote an id.
2. You have a typo `commendid` should be `commentid`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var commentid = "comment";

    $("#" + commentid).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahil, just spotted it!

Comment: Yes, cant believe missed the typo... just testing now. And also the # is an obvious one... live and learn from the simple mistakes :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add the '#'. This indicates an id

```
var commentid = "#comment";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing '#' symbol :)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){     
  $('#comment').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var commentid = "#comment";
 $(commentid).css({'background-color': 'yellow'}); 
});
```